# add values to a input like "input_name[]" on change multiple select with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a hidden input I have...

```
 <input name="input_name[]" type="hidden"/>
```

I would like to add values to this input as soon as I "onchange" a multiple select options like:

```
<select id="inputSelect" multiple>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

The place where put the javascript o even if is a function, is irrelevant to me.

I would accept an answer for javascript solution but if someone give a jquery solution I would take as important information and I would really thank that.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using core Javascript. It works by attaching an event listener to the `<select>` input, then running a function to set the value of the hidden `<input>`.

To target the hidden `<input>` we can use `document.getElementsByName` and use the name of `input_name[]`. If you have more than 1 element with this name you'll need to change the index in the square brackets in `inputHidden[0].value = newValue;` to the correct index. In this case, since there is one element with a name of `input_hidden[]` we use index `0`. If there were 2 elements, and you wanted to set the value of the 2nd hidden `<input>` you would use `inputHidden[1].value = newValue;`

```js
var inputSelect = document.getElementById('inputSelect');
   
inputSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var newValue = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < inputSelect.length; i++) {
    if (inputSelect[i].selected) {
      newValue.push(inputSelect[i].value);
    }
  }

  var inputHidden = document.getElementsByName('input_name[]');
  inputHidden[0].value = newValue.join(",");
});
```

```html
<input name="input_name[]" type="hidden" id="inputHidden"/>
<select id="inputSelect" multiple>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Miguel - do you have multiple Selects? In your example you're Select has an `id`, do the other Selects have IDs? Or classes?

Comment: Is a <select> where you can choose more than one <option>, I didn't say I have more than one <select>.  In my example , values 1, 2,3,4 should be added to the hiden "input_name[]" input. @BrettDeWoody

Comment: Yes, that is what my code example does. If you inspect the example, when you change the Select it updates the value of the hidden input.

Comment: I do thank you for your answer @BrettDeWoody but to be a "Multiple" <select> it should have "multiple" atribute so <input id="inpuSelect" multipe="multiple">

Comment: I have updated the solution to handle selects that allow multiple selections.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery example:

```js
$('#inputSelect').on('change', function(){
 var newVal = $(this).val();
 $('#inputHidden').val(newVal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input_name[]" id="inputHidden"/>
<select id="inputSelect" multiple>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```